# Iterate PHP Array of files and delete any files that have no content

Tags: php

I have an array of files with full directory path to each file.  I need to iterate my files array and then delete ay of the files that are 0byte/non content inside them.

**files.txt**

```
/lib/Zend/Gdata/App/LoggingHttpClientAdapterSocket.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/App/Extension.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/App/MediaEntry.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/App/FeedEntryParent.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/App/AuthException.php
/lib/Zend/ProgressBar/Adapter.php
/lib/Zend/ProgressBar/alias.php
/lib/Zend/Locale/code.php
/lib/Zend/Server/Reflection/Function/article.php
/lib/Zend/Server/Reflection/ReturnValue.php
/lib/Zend/Server/Reflection.php
/lib/Zend/Dojo/BuildLayer.php
/lib/Zend/Tag/Cloud/start.php
/lib/Zend/Tag/Cloud/user.php
/lib/Zend/Tag/Item.php
/lib/Zend/Tag/Cloud.php
/lib/Zend/Ldap/Filter/Not.php
/lib/Zend/Ldap/Filter/And.php
/lib/Zend/Ldap/Filter/Exception.php
/lib/Zend/Ldap/Node.php
/lib/Zend/Ldap/Exception.php
```

**PHP**

```
// list of files to download
$lines = file('files.txt');

// Loop through our array of files from the files.txt file
foreach ($lines as $line_num =>$file) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($file) . "<br />\n";

    // delete empty files
}
```

Comment: and the problem is? Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: @Robert When I get to each file in my text file I have the file path to the file but I need help checking too see if it is an empty file and if it is then I need to delete the file.  If not empty ignore and check the next file

Comment: @JasonDavis Please update your question

Answer (score 2):

Your base loop looks good so far, I think what you'll be interested in next are [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php):

```
$lines = file('files.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $file) {
    $file_label = htmlspecialchars($file);
    echo $file_label . "<br />\n";

    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        echo "file " . $file_label . " does not exist<br />\n";
    } else if (filesize($file) === 0) {
        echo "deleting file: " . $file_label . "<br />\n";
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Though you should really be careful with this to make sure it only deletes files within specific directories, potentially have a whitelist of files that should never be deleted, etc.

**Update** A good note from a comment is to use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` in the `file()` call to strip `\r` and `\n` characters from each line returned =]

Comment: Little hint: OP probably wants to add the flag: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to the `file()` call, since otherwise he will get the file size of: `xy.php\n`

Comment: This won't work in every case. `filesize()` can return FALSE and you don't use `===` operator. and `false == 0 `is true.

Comment: @JasonDavis You're welcome. I already thought that this will cause a problem :]

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions to do it one is `filesize()` which checks size of file and the other one is `file_exists()` which checks if file exists. To remove file use `unlink()` function.

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num =>$file) {
    if(file_exists($file) && filesize($file) === 0) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good.  The size check is what I needed help with so I tried `echo $file . ': ' . filesize($file) . ' bytes<hr>';` however it returns empty value for each file based on a path like this `/lib/Zend/Tag/Cloud/start.php` any ideas

Comment: it may not be empty but false which is different. filesize() will return false if there are errors while reading file, for example permissions. You need also make cure that path is correct which can be done with file_exists()

Comment: Issue was the missing `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag in `files()`